# How to create a date picking input field using Atlassian's calendar component with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, calendar, atlaskit

All I want is a simple date input field for the user to pick a date. The user clicks on the input field, which opens a calendar (in this case we are using Atlassian), user picks the date and the calendar shuts but keeps the input field with the chosen date.

As it is right now all I have is the calendar component, which I have no idea how to interact with or get the data from and no documentation to tell me how.
Here is roughly what my current code is:
    import Calendar from '@atlaskit/calendar'

```
export default class DateInputForm {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <Calendar 
            onSelect={()=> {console.warn('do something!!)}}
            onChange={()=> {console.warn('do something!!)}}/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Edit: as was suggested to me, I created the component with an input field and the Calendar, however I still can't grab the values picked from Calendar.

```
export default class DatePicker extends React.Component {
  static propTypes ={
    value: PropTypes.string
  }
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      calendarOpened: false
    }
  }

  openCalendar () {
    this.setState({calendarOpened: true})
  }

  render () {
    const { value } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <input
        value={value || 'yyyy-mm-dd'}
        onClick={() => this.openCalendar()} />
        {this.state.calendarOpened
          ? <Calendar
            onSelect={() => {console.warn('do something!!)}}
            onChange={() => {console.warn('do something!!)}}/>
          : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Edit2: I should probably note that absolutely nothing happens during the onSelect and onChange of the Calendar component.
All I want at this point is to have access to whatever date I chose from the Calendar component

Comment: Just a possible idea on how to do this :
1. make your own react component which includes an input field and this calendar component. 
2. Based on the click in input field, you should display the calendar component.
3.  And on onBlur of input field , hide the calendar component.

Comment: OK, so I got that running, however I still have no clue how to actually get the value that I chose from the calendar. I'll update my code to show the changes.

Comment: I need to know how are you calling this DatePicker . You have edited your code to make it a component but still how are you calling your DatePicker component from your HTML or any view file ? Plus your openCalendar function does not have bind method in the constructor and there is no constructor present for this component as well.

Comment: Sorry I cut a bit of the code to not make it very long. I thought the constructor would just be implied, but its there.
The DatePicker component is being called in another component which would be a form (full of other fields). Why would the openCalendar need a bind? I am currently using the arrow function and it is working as intended as far as displaying the Calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Basically had to practically re-write the entire thing and had to user `CalendarStateless` as opposed to just `Calendar` which apparently isn't really editable in the way I wanted to be. [See more details here](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/components/calendar)

Anyway, this was roughly the resulting component:

```
import {CalendarStateless} from '@atlaskit/calendar'

export default class DatePicker extends React.Component {
  static propTypes ={
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      calendarOpened: false,
      selected: [],
      day: new Date().getDate(),
      month: new Date().getMonth() + 1,
      year: new Date().getFullYear()
    }
  }
  // this is for the actual date selection
  selectDate (evt) {
    this.setState({ selected: evt.iso, calendarOpened: false })
  }
  // this is to display different months or years
  // without it we would only have one calendar page
  changeInfo ({ day, month, year }) {
    this.setState({ day, month, year })
  }

  openCalendar () {
    this.setState({calendarOpened: true})
  }

  render () {
    const { value } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <input
        value={value || ''}
        placeholder='yyyy-mm-dd'
        onClick={() => this.openCalendar()} />
        {this.state.calendarOpened
          ? <CalendarStateless
            selected={this.props.value}
            day={this.state.day}
            month={this.state.month}
            year={this.state.year}
            onSelect={(evt) => this.selectDate(evt)}
            onChange={date => this.changeInfo(date)}/>
          : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

```
class DatePicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.openCalendar = this.openCalendar.bind(this);
    this.changeDate = this.changeDate.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      calendarOpened: false,
      selectedDate: null,
    };
}

changeDate(event) {
  this.setState ({
  selectedDate: event.value
  )};
}

openCalendar() {
  this.setState({
    calendarOpened: true,
  });
}
render () {
const { value } = this.props;
return (
  <div>
    <input
    value={this.state.selectedDate || 'yyyy-mm-dd'}
    onClick={() => this.openCalendar()} />
    {this.state.calendarOpened
      ? <Calendar
        onChange={this.changeDate}/>
      : null}
  </div>
)
}
}
```

This is not perfect code and not perfect but i dont know how to reference your npm stuff in codepen or stackoverflow code editor. See if this works out.

Comment: That code would be close to the ideal of what I want to do, however I cannot get onChange on the Calendar component to fire. Nothing happens no matter what I put in there.

Comment: So can you post the console errors in your question ?

Comment: @theJuls are you sure definitiely there must be something presented in the developer consoler ?

Comment: Yup, absolutely nothing appears whenever I attempt to select a date.

Comment: I have figured it out and posted the solution in case anyone else ever needs it. Basically had to change the component completely, use CalendarStateless instead of Calendar and manually implement the events relating to the calendar itself.